# Hibernate Left Join to Subclass returns Proxy

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hql

I have an inheritance hierachy with base class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
abstract Instrument {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "instrument1", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Market> markets;

    abstract Type getType(); // Type is an Enum containing Currency & Commodity
}
```

And two subclasses `Commodity` and `Currency` e.g.

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CUR")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "INS_ID"))
public class Currency extends Instrument {
    ...
    getType() {
        returns Type.Currency;
    }
}
```

Each Instrument can be listed on many Markets:

```
@Entity
public class Market {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "INS_ID")
    private Instrument instrument1; // Currency or Commodity listed on the market

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUR_ID")
    private Currency instrument2; // Base currency of the market
}
```

I have created a `CRUDRepository` method to select all markets along with their instrument and base currencies:

```
@Query("SELECT m FROM Market m LEFT JOIN FETCH m.instrument1 LEFT JOIN FETCH m.instrument2")
public List<Market> findAllMarkets();
```

But for some reason when I try to do something like:

```
findAllMarkets()
    .stream()
    .filter(m -> m.getInstrument1().getType() == Type.Currency)
    .map(m -> (Currency) m.getInstrument1())
    .collect(toList());
```

I get a `ClassCastException` because `Instrument1` is actually a proxy type of `Instrument` rather than `Currency` which I would expect. This seems to happen intermittently, some would be actual `Currency` instances and some `instrument_$$_jvst965_19` proxies.

Is there a way I can force Hibernate not to use Proxies for this query?

Comment: So far it is looking like this is related to hibernate session caching

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion it that this is to do with the Hibernate Session or L2 Cache.

Elsewhere in my application I was querying an entity without the `Left Join Fetch` on instrument e.g. like:

`SELECT m FROM Market m`

I noticed that if I changed this call to also include the `Left Join Fetch` then my issue was resolved. Alternatively calling `findAllMarkets` before the method call without the `Left Join Fetch` also fixed the problem.

To stop this ever happening you can add `@Proxy(lazy=false)` onto your base class e.g.

```
@Proxy(lazy=false)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
abstract Instrument {
    ...
}
```

However this will cause Hibernates n+1 method if you call `SELECT m FROM Market m` as it will select all markets, then load each instrument in a seperate query.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a proxy, it means that one of your market entity is already in the persistence unit. If you don't want a proxy make sure that no market entity is managed before querying the database.